# applying a function with multiple arguments over multiple paired variables in R

Tags: r, function, lapply, data-cleaning, mapply

I have a function like this which im using to clean data and works correctly.

```
my_fun <- function (x, y){
    y <- ifelse(str_detect(x, "-*\\d+\\.*\\d*"), 
        as.numeric(str_extract(x, "-*\\d+\\.*\\d*")),
        as.numeric(y))
}
```

It takes numbers that have been entered in the wrong column and reassigns them to the correct column. It is used as follows to clean the y variable:

```
df$y <- my_fun(x, y)
```

I have many columns/variables (more than 10) that are paired in the same format something like this

```
x_vars <- c("x_1", "x_2", "x_3", "x_4", "x_5", "x_6")
y_vars <- c("y_1", "y_2", "y_3", "y_4", "y_5", "y_6")
```

My question is. Is there a way to apply this function across all the variables in my data set that need to be cleaned in the same way? I can easily do this in other instances where my data cleaning function has only one argument using `lapply` but am struggling in this case.

I have tried `mapply` but could not get it to work, this might be because I'm still quite a novice in R. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should gather/melt your data to a tidier long form, and the operation will be fairly trivial. To make this a useful question, you should edit with a sample of your data, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mapply/Map`.  We need to extract the columns based on the column names by passing the 'x_vars', 'y_vars' as arguments to `Map`, apply the `my_fun` on the extracted the `vector`s, and assign it back to 'y_vars' in the original dataset

```
df[y_vars] <- Map(function(x,y) my_fun(df[,x], df[,y]), x_vars, y_vars)
```

Or this can be also written as

```
df[y_vars] <- Map(my_fun, df[x_vars], df[y_vars])
```

NOTE: Here, we are assuming that all the elements in 'x_vars' and 'y_vars' are columns in the original dataset.  We would also state that using `Map` will be much more faster and efficient than reshaping it to long and then do some conversion.

---

To provide a different approach, we can use the `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(df), measure = list(x_vars, y_vars))[,
               value3 := my_fun(value1, value2), variable]
```

Then, again, we need to `dcast` it back to 'wide' format.  So, it is requires more steps and not much easy

```
setnames(dcast(dM, rowid(variable)~variable, 
  value.var = c("value1", "value3"))[,variable := NULL][], c(x_vars, y_vars))[]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:5, "something 10.5",
   "this -4.5", "what -5.2 value?"),
          12*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=12, dimnames = 
     list(NULL, c(x_vars, y_vars))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

B/c I always think it's good to know how to do this stuff in base R, I've got exmaples of how to use `mapply()` and `lapply()`.

```
## first generate some data
df <- data.frame(replicate(12, rnorm(5)))
my_fun <- function (x, y){
    ifelse(stringr::str_detect(x, "-*\\d+\\.*\\d*"),
        as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(x, "-*\\d+\\.*\\d*")),
        as.numeric(y))
}
df <- data.frame(replicate(12, rnorm(3)))
df[, sample(1:6, 3)] <- letters[1:3]
## not function of interest, but good mapply() example
names(df) <- c(
               mapply(paste0, rep("x_", 6), 1:6),
               mapply(paste0, rep("y_", 6), 1:6))

## print data with problem variables (cols with letters)
#df
#         x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4        x_5        x_6       y_1
#1 -0.2184993   a   a   a -0.1587070 0.37795630 0.6162796
#2  0.8511775   b   b   b  0.5743287 0.15291219 1.0594502
#3  0.8183208   c   c   c  1.8923812 0.07156925 0.8613535
#         y_2        y_3        y_4       y_5        y_6
#1  0.3240393 -1.1084067  0.5233168 0.3712705 -0.3911407
#2  0.3044824 -0.2286032 -1.0019870 1.2156441  0.4010163
#3 -1.0920677  1.3408504  1.3339865 0.3270800 -0.8416253



## if you wrote a for loop, it'd look like this maybe
out <- vector("list", 6)
for (i in seq_len(6)) {
    out[[i]] <- my_fun(df[, i], df[, i + 6])
}

## same construction can be used with lapply
dfy <- lapply(seq_len(6), function(i)
    my_fun(df[, 1:6][[i]],
           df[, 7:12][[i]]))
matrix(unlist(dfy), 5, 6)
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
#[1,] -0.2184993 -1.0920677 -1.0019870  0.37795630  0.8183208
#[2,]  0.8511775 -1.1084067  1.3339865  0.15291219  0.3240393
#[3,]  0.8183208 -0.2286032 -0.1587070  0.07156925  0.3044824
#[4,]  0.3240393  1.3408504  0.5743287 -0.21849928 -1.0920677
#[5,]  0.3044824  0.5233168  1.8923812  0.85117750 -1.1084067
#           [,6]
#[1,] -0.2286032
#[2,]  1.3408504
#[3,]  0.5233168
#[4,] -1.0019870
#[5,]  1.3339865
```

> Warning message:
>       In matrix(unlist(dfy), 5, 6) :
>         data length [18] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [5]

```
## and mapply makes this even easier
mapply(my_fun, df[, 1:6], df[, 7:12])
#            x_1        x_2        x_3        x_4        x_5
#[1,] -0.2184993  0.3240393 -1.1084067  0.5233168 -0.1587070
#[2,]  0.8511775  0.3044824 -0.2286032 -1.0019870  0.5743287
#[3,]  0.8183208 -1.0920677  1.3408504  1.3339865  1.8923812
#            x_6
#[1,] 0.37795630
#[2,] 0.15291219
#[3,] 0.07156925
```